# How to change font awesome in a class?

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have the following 2 classes:

```
.invalid {
    padding-left:22px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#ec3f41;
    class:fa;
}
.valid {
    padding-left:22px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#3a7d34;
}
```

in the invalid class I want to use

> fa-warning

and in valid class I want to use

> fa-check

### HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li id="letter" class="invalid"> At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
</ul>
```

### JQuery:

```
if (pswd.match(/[A-z]/)) {
                        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                    } else {
                        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `How to change font awesome in a class?` doesn't make sense... font-awesome is an icon library

Comment: do you mean to say you need to append another class `fa-warning` to it if `.invalid` is available ?

Comment: @Alaa Hi there is it possible to use a <I> tag in your html? It could be much easier without many css to change the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use fontawesome fonts in your valid and invalid classes.
use like this

```
.valid:before{
         content: "\f046";
         font-family: FontAwesome;  
}

.invalid:before{
         content: "\f00d";
         font-family: FontAwesome;  
 }
```

Working Example: https://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/mmXjbr

For other icons, you can go to http://fontawesome.io/icons/ inspect the icon you want to copy and then from CSS panel in chrome dev tools copy line having 
 `content: "";`

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

I've edited the answer

```
if (pswd.match(/[A-z]/)) {
                        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                        $('#letter').addClass('fa-check');
                    } else {
                        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                        $('#letter').addClass('fa-warning');
                    }
```